# Can't create list item on host web list with remote event receiver

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, list-item

I'm using this code to create a calendar item.

Please note that this used to work, but today, it doesn't. I don't know why and I can't debug it because I'm using app only permissions.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

```
public void createCalendarItem(DateTime startDate,DateTime endDate, Double workDaysRequested, String requesterName)
    {
        string webUrl = "myurlhere";

        //using (ClientContext clientContextWeb = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(propertiesFunction))
        //{
        //    clientContextWeb.Load(clientContextWeb.Web);
        //    clientContextWeb.ExecuteQuery();

        //    webUrl = clientContextWeb.Web.Url; 
        //}

        //string webUrl = properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl;

        Uri webUri = new Uri(webUrl);

        string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(webUri);
        string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, webUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
        var clientContextTest = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(webUrl, accessToken);

        using (var  clientContextAdmin = clientContextTest)
        {
            if (clientContextAdmin != null)
            {
                List calendarList = clientContextAdmin.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("LeaveCalendar");

                clientContextAdmin.Load(calendarList);
                clientContextAdmin.ExecuteQuery();

                ListItemCreationInformation calendaritemCreationInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();

                ListItem calendarItem = calendarList.AddItem(calendaritemCreationInfo);
                calendarItem["Title"] = "Leave Request for " + requesterName + " for " + Convert.ToString(workDaysRequested) + " day(s)";
                calendarItem["EventDate"] = startDate;
                calendarItem["EndDate"] = endDate;


                calendarItem.Update();

                clientContextAdmin.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it SharePoint-hosted app or provider-hosted app?

I think the reason for this may be the authentication of ClientContext.

Please try to do authentication with the code below.

```
 public static void setClientCredential(ClientContext clientContext, string userName, string password, string domain)
 {
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
 }
```